# Why aren't nodes displaying in neo4j graph view when they show up in Table and Text view?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running a simple query on neo4j in an enterprise system. I have been using neo4j for last 3-4 months. So have basic familiarity of cypher queries etc. I am using neo4j browser using Chrome. While working , all of a sudden if I write a simple Cypher query such as "MATCH (c:mynode) return c limit 5" , the result does not show any nodes in "Graph display" window. However the "Table","Text" and "Code" view is displaying results easily. I never had this problem in last 3-4 months that display vanishes all of a sudden.. Tried many things in settings etc..nothing seems to work.. any possible reason for the same?

Tried :reset style, was expecting the nodes would display again as it does normally in graph view. Did not display. All those nodes are however showing in Tables, Text and Code view.

Comment: With further trial I found the answer.. I was somehow able to display only a single node even though it was saying "displaying 25 nodes".. then I clicked on that node and while it creates a halo around that node I just selected the "graph" icon there.. now those additional 25 nodes as defined in limit came back..huh..

Comment: In the Neo4j browser, the "graph" icon on a node expands the relationships from/to that node, so I'm not sure that's doing what you want. The usual reason for a table/code/text to show and not a graph is because the query returns properties: i.e. `RETURN n.Name` vs `RETURN n`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try shift-reload on your Neo4j Browser?

Or check in the javascript console if there are any errors?

What versions are you using?

Sometimes it helps to upgrade to more recent versions?

Or try to use https://browser.neo4j.io for a centrally hosted version.
Or http://browser.graphapp.io for a non-SSL version.